# Произносительные нормы

Tags: орфоэпия

**В каком ряду есть лишнее слово с точки зрения произносительных норм?**

а)конечно, скучно, Ильинична.

б)красного, этого, одного.

в)(она) красива, терпелива, горда.

г) купаться, играется, смеётся.

д)фанера, шинель, музей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В третьем - в слове горда ударение падает на последний слог.

Общее:

В первом ЧН произносится как ШН. Во втором   последний согласный  В. В четвертом на конце звучит ЦА. В последнем перед Е мягкий согласный.

Comment: Субъективно. 
В том счмысле, что вы не рассматриваете альтернативные "версии".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что это второй ряд: "одного". Ср.: [крАснъвъ],[Этъвъ],[аднавО]. Простите, что последняя транскрипция не совсем точная: не нашла нужных значков.

**Добавлю к уже сказанному**. Исключением может быть и слово **Ильинична**, так как его можно употребить двояко: Ильини[Ч]на и Ильини[Ш]на, а в двух других словах первого ряда произносится только [Ш].

Comment: Пожалуй соглашусь.
Это наиболее логичное решение нелогичной задачи.

Comment: Да, но не могу представить, чтобы норма здесь не соблюдалась.(разве что в "окающих" областях.  А вот под влиянием орфографии произношение с Г встречается, особенно при чтении. Но и в предложенном Лораной ответе тоже трудно представить нарушение произношения в указанных словах. А ведь ernest00 просит оценить именно с точки зрения норм.

Answer (score -2):

Вопрос некорректнен. С каких позиций "лишнее"?
В каком-то смысле все тройки содержат лишнее слово.

а) 
Везде [шн] варианты [канечна], [скучна], считаются допустимыми, [ильинична] - вроде бы нет.

б)
[кра'снава], [э'това], [однаво']

в)
Вообще непонятно, "горда" просто не в этом ряду никаким образом

г)
Тут может быть не ЦА, а ТЬ-СЯ отобенно в последнем случае...

д)
А вот это самое веселое.
фанера - единственное слово, где Е идет между мягким и твердым... В таких случаях по общим "произносительным норамам" обычно идет Ё...

Comment: МОжет и ТЬ_- СЯ, но в соответствии с произносительными нормами - ЦА.

Comment: Это очень спорное утверждение.
А в императивах "пяться", "отметься", "втреться", "позаботься" тоже ЦА? Если да, то прождолжать бессмыссленно, мы на принципиально разных позициях.

Comment: Я имела в виду инфинитив и 3 лицо - веди именно такие примеры в вопросе.

Comment: Я понимаю, какие примеры в вопросе. Я не понимаю, что означает ваше утверждение о произносительных нормах. Утверждение спорно, если вас не затруднит, ответьте, пожалуйста, на мой вопрос.